# Text Handle uicontrol Not Updating Correctly Within a Callback Function

Tags: matlab, uicontrol

I have four `progress` messages I need to be displayed within a `text_h`, but only the first '*Loading audio...*', the second '*Computing valence features...*', and the last '*Done!!!*' are being displayed.  The third message '*Computing arousal features...*' seems to be getting lost in the process.  I also would like to know how I can get each message to stay within the `text_h` with a new message being printed to the line below, so I can see all the processes?

```
function guiUpload(upload_button_h, evt, text_h, list_h, tracks, models)

    global predict_arousal
    global predict_valence

    %% print to progress monitor
    progress = 'Loading Audio...';
    set(text_h, 'String', progress);

    %% get reference to wave file
    [filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'.wav'}, 'File Selector'); % {} filter file type
    complete_path = strcat(pathname,filename);  % concat both strings together

    %% convert complete_path to WAV with samp freq
    [x,fs] = audioread(complete_path);
    x = sum(x, 2); % convert to monophonic by averaging

    %% trim leading and trailing zeros from WAV vector
    x = x(find(x,1,'first'):find(x,1,'last'));

    %% print to progress monitor
    progress = 'Computing Valence Features...';
    set(text_h, 'String', progress);

    %% get short-term spread [2xN], then convert to [1xN]
    st_spread = stSpread(x, fs, 0.02, 0.01);
    st_spread = st_spread(2,:);  % get spread (2), not centroid (1)!

    %% get mid-term statistics spread [2xN] 1 mean, 2 median
    v_stat = {'mean', 'median'};
    mt_spread = mtFeatureExtraction(st_spread, 3, 3, v_stat);

    %% get global mean of spread statistics
    mean_spread = mean(mt_spread(1,:));
    median_spread = mean(mt_spread(2,:));

    %% get global spectral flatnesss statistic - MIR TOOLBOX 1.6.1
    flatness = mirflatness(complete_path);
    flatness = get(flatness, 'Data');
    flatness = flatness{1,1}{1,1};

    %% get valence predictions for spread and flatness
    predict_spread = models.valence.spread(mean_spread);
    predict_med_spread = models.valence.med_spread(median_spread);
    predict_flatness = models.valence.flatness(flatness);

    %% test valence predictions to see if they are greater or less than -4, 4
    predict_spread = guiTestPrediction(predict_spread);
    predict_med_spread = guiTestPrediction(predict_med_spread);
    predict_flatness = guiTestPrediction(predict_flatness);

    %% average all valence predictions
    valence = mean([predict_spread predict_med_spread predict_flatness]);

    %% add valence statistic to predictions structure
    predict_valence(end+1) = valence;

    %% print to progress monitor
    progress = 'Computing Arousal Features...';
    set(text_h, 'String', progress);

    %% get short-term energy [1xN]
    st_energy = stEnergy(x, fs, 0.02, 0.01);

    %% get mid-term statistics energy [3xN] 1 mean, 2 std, 3 median
    a_stat = {'mean', 'std', 'median'};
    mt_energy = mtFeatureExtraction(st_energy, 3, 3, a_stat);

    %% get global mean of energy statistics
    mean_energy = mean(mt_energy(1,:));
    std_energy = mean(mt_energy(2,:));
    median_energy = mean(mt_energy(3,:));

    %% get arousal predictions for energy
    predict_energy = models.arousal.energy(mean_energy);
    predict_std_energy = models.arousal.std_energy(std_energy);
    predict_med_energy = models.arousal.med_energy(median_energy);

    %% test arousal predictions to see if they are greater or less than -4, 4
    predict_energy = guiTestPrediction(predict_energy);
    predict_std_energy = guiTestPrediction(predict_std_energy);
    predict_med_energy = guiTestPrediction(predict_med_energy);

    %% average all arousal predictions
    arousal = mean([predict_energy predict_std_energy predict_med_energy]);

    %% add arousal statistic to predictions structure
    predict_arousal(end+1) = arousal;

    %% add new filename to the end of the tracks array
    tracks{end+1} = filename;

    %% re-populate list_h with new songs array
    set(list_h, 'String', tracks);

    %% print to progress monitor
    progress = 'Done!!!';
    set(text_h, 'String', progress);
end
```

My code for the `text_h` is as follows:

```
text_position = [0.025 0.05 0.95 0.90];
text_h = uicontrol('Parent', text_panel_h, 'Style', 'text','FontSize', 12,'HorizontalAlignment', 'Left','BackgroundColor','white','units', 'normalized', 'position', text_position, 'String', '');
```

Comment: Are you sure it's being lost and not that the execution of the subsequent tasks is faster than anticipated?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, would you suggest a delay in between each of the four processes?

Comment: No, why would you want to artificially slow down your program? I would suggest learning how to utilize [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html), all of your questions so far can be simply investigated on your own.

Comment: Ok, will do as I have a lot more user GUIs to build over the next few months

Answer (score 0):

If your `text_h` is big enough to hold all messages, you can try to update its `String` with new message instead of rewrite it to keep all messages:

```
% example of initialized text
set(text_h, 'String', 'test 1');
% update its String property
set(text_h, 'String', [get(text_h, 'String'); 'here is the new message']);
```

Note that `get(text_h, 'String')` will return a cell array of strings if you are using multiple lines.

Comment: A text `uicontrol` accepts cell arrays of strings and displays each cell on a new line, there's no reason to concatenate strings. Add a new cell.

Comment: how would you add the new cell without set and get? as i know, unless you have r2014b+, you cannot write directly `text_h.String{end+1} = 'new message';`